Fermi tetrad field: Fermi-Walker tetrad formalism?
These days I'm reading Dirac Eq in GR, and I'm confused about "Fermi tetrad field". Is it Fermi-Walker tetrad formalism?

I don't see the phrase "Fermi Tetrad" anywhere in your linked  wiki article.
The usual "tetrad" is defined defined  at all points in spacetime, but the Fermi-Walker  frame, being a Lorentz analogue of the Seret-Frenet frame, is defined only on a curve.
